# why in type_traits remove_reference is specialized?

Tags: c++

type_traits

```
template<typename _Tp>
    struct remove_reference
    { typedef _Tp   type; };

template<typename _Tp>
    struct remove_reference<_Tp&>
    { typedef _Tp   type; };

template<typename _Tp>
    struct remove_reference<_Tp&&>
    { typedef _Tp   type; };
```

They do the same thing, so why do we need template specialization there?

Comment: It's in the name right, `remove_reference` ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They don't do the same thing. They are specialized for reference and rvalue references to remove the references from the types.

Comment: They don't do the same thing, they remove reference by converting referenced type into a raw one (T& -> T, T&& -> T).